# Error when calling .setAttribute() on element's first child

Tags: javascript, setattribute

My code doesn't seem to be working.  I am trying to access the first child of the div and set an attribute, but the console gives me this error:

> `TypeError: Object # has no method 'setAttribute'`

My Code:

```
<div>
    <p id="one"><span id="uno">1</span></p>
    <p id="two"><span id="dos">2</span></p>
    <p id="three"><span id="tres">3</span></p>  
</div>
<script>
var divvy = document.getElementsByTagName("div").item(0)
divvy.firstChild.setAttribute("style", "color: violet;");
</script>
```

Comment: and the error is....?

Comment: since you have whitespace between your element tags (`div> <p id="one">`) the firstChild is a textnode which does not have a setAttribute function.

Comment: it's in the title, sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `.children` collection to avoid the text node.

```
divvy.children[0].setAttribute("style", "color: violet;");
```

---

In modern browsers (like IE9+), you can use `.firstElementChild` instead of `.firstChild`.

```
divvy.firstElementChild.setAttribute("style", "color: violet;");
```

---

And off topic, but I wouldn't use `setAttribute` to set the color. I'd use the `.style` property.

```
divvy.firstElementChild.style.color = "violet";
```

Comment: Nice. I did not know about firstElementChild. Looks like it's IE9+, in case anyone else was wondering.

Comment: in modern browser you might as well use querySelector/querySelectorAll

Comment: @PatrickEvans: I'm pretty sure the more primitive DOM methods are still quite a bit more efficient than querySelector. Not that it matters in many cases, but it still matters often enough to bear in mind.

Comment: @PatrickEvans: I'd probably use `.children` over `querySelector` if we know it's the first element. Though `.querySelector` will work in IE8 while `.firstElementChild` won't.

Comment: @Chuck, true, but i meant from overall, as he is calling `getElementsByTagName("div")` it builds an nodelist of every single div in the document and then only uses the one(though in the snippet provided it would just be one anyway but what document actually has only one div). Meant it would probably be better to call a function that would just retrieve the one element needed right off the bat. Didn't mean that instead of using `children` to do the query call.

Comment: Is there a method similar to 'firstElementChild' that ignores white space but for 'nextSibling'?  I'm getting the same white space error when I use 'nextSibling' and I would much prefer not to remove the white space.

Comment: @user192938: `.nextElementSibling`

Answer (score 0):

The first child of the DIV is a text node containing the empty space before the P elements. Instead, try this:

```
var divvy = document.getElementsByTagName("div").item(0)
divvy.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].setAttribute("style", "color: violet;");
```

This explicitly selects the first P element.